# How to Create File Geodatabase in home folder OR get it to ask (using model builder)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, file-geodatabase

Im using Model Builder to try and create a GDB with 3 Datasets.

I would like the GDB to either be placed within the folder that the .mxd is saved, or I'd like a prompt, for where to save it.

Can anyone help?!

[Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVLEV.png)

Comment: You might want to try using Python for this rather than ModelBuilder

Comment: You need model parameters. Give this a read: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//002w0000003z000000

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [Parse Path (ModelBuilder)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//004000000008000000) tool with the input being your MXD. The resulting PATH will be your input to the [Create File GDB (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//0017000000pw000000) tool.  Below is a simple model showing this.  It seems that you cannot use the output value from the Parse path tool as a direct input into the Create File GDB tool.  This is probably because the `File GDB Location` parameter is expecting a file data type.  Just use [inline variable substitution](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//002w0000005w000000) and connect it as a precondition.

[image: Example Model]

[Full Size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxull.png)

This would be a method to use if you do not want to user to manually specify the location where the GDBs will be created and they are already supplying an MXD to the tool.  Look for @KHibma's comment on your original question for asking the user where it should be saved in the form of a model parameter.